# I want to make an Android API to keep a screen wake in home screen

Tags: java, android

I want to make an api that makes the screen awake.
I have tried this way:

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);`

But this is only available when app is running foreground.
If I leave this app, the screen is turn off after a few seconds.
I want somebody to help me with making this api.
Thank you.

Comment: If you create a Launcher app, you can keep the homescreen on. But your app can't tell other apps to keep the screen on.

Answer (score 0):

you can use wakelock screen to wakeup the device using api

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#java